# how to get more records with same foreign key in many to many relationship using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get more records of same foreign key.

**Model code:**
Modael name is Teacher, method for many to many relation is 'courses' and workloads is povit table

```
public function courses(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class,'workloads','course_id','id');
}
```

**controller code:**
In controller I want to get all records but all recodrs is not fetched, those records is remained which 'id' is same

```
 $teachers = Teacher::with('courses:id,courseName')->get(['id','name']);
```

**blade code:**
In blade only two teachers records are displayed but povite table have three records, the third one record does not fetched because its teacher_id is same and get the first mached id record and remain second id record

```
@foreach ($teachers as $teacher)
  <option value="{{ $teacher->id}}">{{ __($teacher->name) }}</option>
@endforeach
```

**DataBase image:**

[image: povit table image 'workloads']
**Expectation:**
I want to get all teachers and its courses which assigned by povit table 'workloads' to him.

Comment: Are you meaning you want to get the courses assigned by each teachers? Or did you want to get teachers by each courses?

Comment: yes sir I want to get the coureses assign to each teachers, and when two coureses assign to same teacher in same class then the above code get two time teacher name but coures  is one time mean the first course name is fetched which accure in database table.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, your current code can only fetch the same id record once, but you want the repeated records to be selected together, right?

Comment: Can you share full code of your Model relation into your question?

Comment: Thank you sir! Now I solve the problem, I will post the answer, sir I think the problem is coming due to violating the pivot table naming convention. Sir model code is already posted.